# Apache Commons net API wont't work on Android ICS(4.0)

Tags: android, apache, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, ftp-client

I have been testing the Apache commons API 3.1 on android 2.1,and it was working fine so far. Now I'm trying to use it on Android ICS(4.0) but I'm running into a problem: the application throws a unhandled exception when I used the "ftp.connect" Command

Here is just a simple code, just to show when the application crashes:

```
 FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient(); //so far is ok

   try {
      ftp.connect("127.0.0.1",21); //<-throws a unhandled exception (used to work on android 2.1)

    } catch (Exception e){
      Log.e("error",e.getMessage());// it doesn't reach this block
   }
```

This is what I have in my logCat:

```
W/dalvikvm(1105): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
```

Does anyone have any idea of what's happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are facing the popular [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). You need to have the network and internet access statements in a separate thread (not in the same thread as main) or in an Async Task. More explanation in an older StackOverflow thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: You were right, that was the problem. I placed the code inside a thread and now it's working normally. Thank you!